# Importing Sets in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

When I am trying to use sets it's showing that there is nothing named set.

```
from sets import set

> ImportError: cannot import name set
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 13):

You don't *need* to import the [`sets` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html); sets are built in now. Just use the built-in [`set()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead:

```
>>> set()
set([])
```

You can use the `{1, 2, 3}` set literal syntax too:

```
>>> {1, 2, 3}
set([1, 2, 3])
```

If you want to use the slower `sets` module anyway, the object is called `Set` with a capital `S`:

```
>>> from sets import Set
```

but note that the module has been deprecated; using it does not add anything over the built-in types. The module has been removed altogether in Python 3.

Comment: @mgilson: Correct, and it only works for non-empty sets. The empty `{}` syntax creates a `dict` instead.

Comment: I saw a comment the other day implying that there should be a frozenset literal:  `f{1,2,3}` ... I thought that was an interesting suggestion -- Although I don't necessarily like it.  I still wish we had more brackets to play with.  using `{..}` for both set and dictionary (and their respective comprehensions) is slightly unfortunate ... But I don't have any alternative to propose :)

Comment: Interesting; personally I don't mind typing `frozenset()` but I can see the advantage.

Comment: What would be the best way to write code using sets that would work in all versions of Python (before and after 2.7, including 3.x) that have the module or the built-in?

Comment: @martineau: `try:\n   set\nexcept NameError:\n    from sets import Set as set\n` and avoid using the `{}` literal syntax. The API is *mostly* the same (see the [comparison in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#comparison-to-the-built-in-set-types)).

Comment: @martineau: Nah; the number of people still using Python 2.5 or before is dwindling fast.

Answer (score 1):

`set` needs to be capitalized:

```
from sets import Set
```

But from Python 2.7 on, `set` is built-in and using `sets#Set` is actually quite a bit slower than the built-in `set`.

For example, a coding challenge I recently evaluated that does a lot of look-up of small words in a `dict` or `set` takes ~3s to run with `sets#Set` but ~1.8s with built-in `set`. It's a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'S' instead of s

```
 try:
    from sets import Set
 except ImportError:
    Set = set
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` instead of `set` because its a keyword.

```
from sets import Set
```